# Why is the command rm called when the system starts up

Tags: linux, rm, permission-denied

My PC is Mac pro.

I removed `x` for `rm` in case of delete files by accident:
`sudo chmod o-x /bin/rm`

However, when I reboot my PC, I got one message on the terminal:

> -bash: /bin/rm: Permission denied

If I do `o+x` for `bin/rm`, the message will disappear.

So I just want to know that which files are automatically removed when the system starts up.

Comment: `chmod o-x /bin/rm`? That's insane. Who knows how many processes may need to delete files for whatever reason? Better create an alias or something instead of this.

Comment: or write a wrapper around /bin/rm that displays the parent process and/or parameters, then calls the real rm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of cleanup at startup, for example removing files in `/tmp`.
So you shouldn't change `/bin/rm` permissions.

If you fear to delete files by accident you can alias rm to rm -i so that you will be always prompted for confirmation.
`alias rm='rm -i'` in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` or equivalent.